# How to add inline input elements between texts

Tags: html

I am trying to create a form similar to this.
But i am finding it very hard to show text inline with form elements.

Form will be something like this:
I certify that the beneficial owner is a resident of ____ within the meaning of the income tax treaty between the United States and that country______ Some text here.
(i want to place text fields in place of dots)

Comment: Why are you finding it hard? Input fields are inline elements by default, so you should just be able to insert them inside your text...

Comment: can you provide the sample code

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> I certify that the beneficial owner is a resident of   <input type="text" /> </p>
```

Put everything inside a p (paragraph) tag.

Copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

input {
  outline:none;
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  max-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  I certify that <input type="text"> within the meaning of the income tax treaty between the United States and that country <input type="text">
</form>
```

Note that `<input>` elements are inline elements unless specified to be otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Check this! is this what you need?

```
<form>
    <p>    
        Form will be something like this: I certify that the beneficial owner is a resident of <input type="text"></input> within the meaning of the income tax treaty between the United States and that country <input type="text"></input>.
    </p>
</form>
```